# Getting error "No Value Given for One or More Parameters" when trying to read from an Access Database with C# and Windows Forms

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I'm writing a very simple program that comes up with a serial Number for computer systems that we make and stores the information about the systems with the serial number in an access file. I'm able to create the new row but I'm getting the error "No Value Given for One or More Parameters" when trying to read from the database searching for a given serial number. Here is my code for the search:

```
private void btn_Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filePath = @"c:\serial\Settings.txt";

            try
            {
                // Check if the file exists
                if (File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    // Read the first line using StreamReader
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
                    {
                        string dataBaseLocation = reader.ReadLine();
                        //MessageBox.Show(dataBaseLocation);
                        string newConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + dataBaseLocation;
                        // Read the auto-incremented key value from a TextBox, assuming the TextBox is named textBoxKey
                        //MessageBox.Show(txtBox_SNLookUp.Text);
                        if (long.TryParse(txtBox_SNLookUp.Text, out long keyValue))
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("The Value of keyValue is " + keyValue);
                            try
                            {
                                using (OleDbConnection newConnection = new OleDbConnection(newConnectionString))
                                {
                                    newConnection.Open();

                                    // SQL query to fetch data from a specific table in the new database
                                    string query = "SELECT * FROM [Serial Numbers] WHERE [Serial Numbers] = @Key";

                                    MessageBox.Show(query);

                                    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, newConnection))
                                    {
                                        // Add the parameter to the command
                                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Key", keyValue);

                                        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
                                        DataTable serial_Data_Table = new DataTable();

                                         // Fill the DataTable with data from the new database
                                        adapter.Fill(serial_Data_Table); // This is line 552 that has an error.

                                        // Set the DataGridView's DataSource to the new DataTable
                                        dataGridView_SerialNumbers.DataSource = serial_Data_Table;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                // Handle any exceptions that may occur during the database operation
                                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
                                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                                richTextBox_Software.Text = ex.ToString();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Invalid key value.");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The file does not exist.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error occurred look hard: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

The Access file sets the serial number as an auto increment key. I have double checked all the variables to make sure they are accurate the only one I don't seem to be able to get the value of is the @Key. This has my error traps in it still giving me popups with variables being shown during runtime.
The following is the complete error that I'm getting through the debugging:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E10): No value given for one or more required parameters.
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
   at Serial_Numbers.SLT_SSI.btn_Search_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\ccran\OneDrive - Star Light Technologies inc\General\Star light tech\Serial Numbers\Serial Numbers\Serial Numbers\Form1.cs:line 552
```

I market line 552

I have tried to put in the serial number instead of a variable but still got the same error. I have tried to error trap but with no avail. I have also tried to determine which parameter is empty or null. I have had an AI look at the code saying that the syntax is correct and that the database is set up correctly so there should be no problems.

I am getting an exceptions thrown:
System.InvalidOperationException
HResult=0x80131509
Message=Command parameter[0] '' data value could not be converted for reasons other than sign mismatch or data overflow.

Source=System.Data
StackTrace:
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
at Serial_Numbers.SLT_SSI.btn_Search_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\ccran\OneDrive - Star Light Technologies inc\General\Star light tech\Serial Numbers\Serial Numbers\Serial Numbers\Form1.cs:line 552

Inner Exception 1:
OleDbException: Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.

Comment: Are you sure that your table [Serial Numbers] has a field named as well [Serial Numbers]? Or the field is named [Serial Number] (singular)?

Comment: Yes they are both plural that was the first thing I looked for.

Comment: Then try to change one of the twos to make them different. Perhaps this is confusing for the sql parser.

Comment: Tried that and getting the same errors

Comment: Also getting an Exception thrown:  Exceprion thrown at 0x00007FF8D3B04B2C (KernelBase.dll) in Serial Numbers.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x83750007 : "input':Value must not be empty.'.

Comment: that exception disappeared when I changed the names back to Serial Numbers.

Comment: Another MS-Access mistery.

Comment: Try this: `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Key", keyValue);`

Comment: That allowed the Header row to load but didn't load any record. I tried getting rid of the @ in front of it in the query as well but it crashed the program when I did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Access and C# read the auto incremented Serials field differently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piuYz.png)

As shown in the image above, I changed the code to show the entire data base (only 2 records) and the Serials (used to be Serial Numbers) is different in both. I had a format setup in access that would set the serial number to 202307000x1 but c# only reads the x. looks like I should try and fix this some how so that the format is read correctly. But if I put x into my program it will pull up the correct record.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first up, I would always for every table have an auto number PK value for each row.

However, that auto number PK is NOT to be exposed to the user, and the user does not care and should not care about some PK value. Those auto number PK values are for you the developer, and NOT the user.

If you have some serial number column? Then build that column as 100% separate from the PK used by your code and system internal.

Also, adopt code in which you strong type any C# data operations. (Dump use of Add with for parameters).

And somewhat confusing that you are asking for one primary key value from the user, but then sending the results to a data grid. Would not that result in ONLY one row each time?

Regardless, don't use or expose the primary key value to the end user. If you have some invoice number, or serial number or whatever? Then add a new column to the database for that purpose. (But leave the PK value alone, and don't try and use the auto number value for external meaning to the end user).

So, I would suggest this code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtBox_SNLookU.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter serial number", "No entry");
            return;
        }
        if (!int.TryParse(txtBox_SNLookU.Text, out int SerialNum))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number", "");
            return;
        }
        string strSQL = @"SELECT * FROM [Serial Numbers] 
                        WHERE [Serial Numbers] = @Key";
        OleDbCommand cmdSQL = new OleDbCommand(strSQL);
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Key", OleDbType.Integer).Value = SerialNum;
        dataGridView_SerialNumbers.DataSource = General.MyRstP(cmdSQL);
    }
```

And then add to your project a static General class (so you don't have to re-create it each time you use).

So, in this project wide handy dandy helper library of code then say like this:

```
public static class General
{
    public static string sSettingsFile = @"c:\test\settings.txt";
    public static string dbPath = "";
    public static string GetConStr()
    {
        if (dbPath == "")
            dbPath = File.ReadAllLines(sSettingsFile)[0];

        return $@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={dbPath}";
    }

    public static DataTable MyRstP(OleDbCommand cmd)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(GetConStr()))
        {
            using (cmd)
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    rstData.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }       
}
```

So, now with any form, or any code you write you don't have to repeat writing of such connection code, and code to return a data table.

Also, note that from MS-access, a long number column is an integer value in c#. So, you don't really need nor want to use the long data type in c#, as that is a x64 bit long integer value, but the long data type in MS-access is a x32 bit sized value.

Hence, use int in C# for the equivalent of a long in MS-access tables.

Comment: Thank you I will take that in to account for the next program I write. This one is only used for internal use by myself and my business partner to create and look up serial numbers for the computers we build. But I do agree with what you said and as I am new to C# I used code that I could get and learned off ai for syntax and for access database building never have used access before. But thank you again.